# How to computer the Lagrange multipliers associated with an optimal solution

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Suppose I have a solution $x^*\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to the following problem

\begin{align*}
\text{minimize}_{x}& \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)\\
\text{subject to}\quad &g_i(x) = 0\,\,i=1,\ldots,m\\
&h_i(x) \le 0\,\,i=1,\ldots,p
\end{align*}

How would I go about computing the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda_i$ associated with the equality constraint $g_i(x) = 0$?

I know that the Lagrangian is 
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda,\mu) = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x) - \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_ig_i(x) - \sum_{i=1}^p\mu_ih_i(x)
\end{align*}
but I'm unsure where to go from here in order to actually get a $value$ for $\lambda_i$ given the optimal solution $x^*$.

Comment: It depends on the problem. There is no general formula other than the one that comes from stationary points of the Lagrangian.

Comment: @copper.hat Is it always possible to find the associated Lagrange multipliers given a solution $x^*$? Can you provide a hint at how it would be done for a specific case? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. There are a few subtleties here. To answer what I think you are asking, no - if the constraints define the solution then the cost doesn't even appear. For a trivial example, $\min \{ f(x) | x = 1 \}$. The solution is $x=1$ regardless of $f$, of course.

Comment: Another example would be $\min \{ {1 \over 2} \langle x, Ax \rangle | \|x\|^2 = 1 \}$ where $A$ is real & symmetric. Then at a stationary point of the Lagrangian we have $Ax -\lambda x = 0$, which shows that the multiplier must be an eigenvalue of $A$. This gives us information about the structure of the problem. In this case, since the potential minimizers are unit eigenvectors, we see the solution is $\lambda_\min$.

Comment: In general, you write out the equation ${ \partial L(x,\lambda, \mu) \over \partial x} = 0$ and see if this can be used to compute the multiplier or the form thereof.

Answer (score 0):

You have an inequality as a constraint. So I would use the **Kuhn-Tucker conditions** (KKT).

But you have an equalility, too. It can be split as follows:

$g_i(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} g_i(x) \leq 0 \\ \\ g_i(x) \geq 0 \end{cases} \Leftrightarrow \begin{cases} g_i(x) \leq 0 \\ \\- g_i(x) \leq 0 \end{cases} $

$max \ \mathcal L=-\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x)+\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_ig_i(x)-\sum_{i=1}^m \Theta_ig_i(x)+\sum_{i=1}^p \mu_ih_i(x)$

By using KKT, $\mathcal L$ will allways be maximized. So I take here $-f_i(x)$ to minimize $f_i(x)$.

greetings,

calculus